# Transaction propagation in multiple servlet context with multiple data source

Tags: spring, transactions, rmi, propagation

We have modularised our application in clustered architecture  like multiple servlet context with different datasource using hibernate and packaging in muliple war files. For eg: moldule1->hibernate sessionfactrory ->datasource 1(module1.war), moldule2->hibernate sessionfactrory ->datasource 2(module2.war)....

Spring RMI is used to integrate module1 and module2 services.

Here my question is, how to  propagate the transaction between these modules, so that when module 2 fails to insert then module1 should roll back?

Comment: You're trying to implement two-phase commit?

Comment: It sounds like OP wants to use XA via EJB-style distributed transaction propagation, not implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't without using EJB, per the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html):

> Spring's support for RMI, you can transparently expose your services through the RMI infrastructure. After having this set up, you basically have a configuration similar to remote EJBs, except for the fact that **there is no standard support for security context propagation or remote transaction propagation**.

...and:

> Last but not least, **EJB has an advantage over RMI in that it supports standard role-based authentication and authorization and remote transaction propagation**.