# Distributing business logic across different servers(like JBoss/Glassfish) using Spring and still under one transaction

Tags: spring, jboss7.x, glassfish-3, distributed-transactions, spring-remoting

I am willing to create an example(code) using Spring in which business logic to be distibuted across different servers like JBoss or Glassfish and still under one transaction? First of all is this possible in Spring. I know using EJB has this option. Likewise do we have a similar technique in Spring also? I am looking for Synchronous communication approach and not using asynchronous message oriented middleware. Any help/pointer appreciated.

Thanks
Prakash

Answer (score 1):

Spring has support for RMI or provides its own remoting mechamism [HttpInvoker](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html) but according to the doc they don't provide any remote transaction propagation.

Similar questions:

- [Spring Distributed Transaction Involving RMI calls possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148090/spring-distributed-transaction-involving-rmi-calls-possible)
- [Transaction propagation in multiple servlet context with multiple data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508220/transaction-propagation-in-multiple-servlet-context-with-multiple-data-source)